# Year 10 - Trigonometry

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

[image]

Please ignore the pencilled 4m in the diagram but I really need to know what the length of the bottom line - line DC - is. A procedure or tips on how to calculate this would be useful. Also, is the pencil line from point C dividing right angle ACD exactly in half? I figured this would be useful to calculate the solution to this problem but I doubt that it is dividing right angle ACD exactly in half. Please use correct rules and explain all working and reasons for this.

Comment: It'd be much better if you put that the diagram in your own question, but however you do it: at least put the diagram **straight** !

Comment: I apologise DonAntonio, another user has corrected this and I was unaware that this was even the case. I am new to this website and am on a mobile device so it is not the easiest to view. Would you be able to help me to find the length of DC as asked in the question?

Comment: no need to apologize. Now, no: the pencil line from $\;C\;$ (=the height to the triangle's hypotenuse) does not bisect that right angle **unless** the right-angled triangle is also isosceles, and in which case it'll also bisect side $\;AD\;$

Comment: Thankyou, do you have any suggestions on how to calculate the length of side CD? I had a few options I could have used to calculate it if this had bisected the right angle, however I don't know how to calculate it now

Answer (score 2):

Developed hints:

Put $\;\angle BDC=x\;$ , and now

$$\begin{cases}I&\text{On triangle}\;\Delta ABC:&\;\;\frac{\tan 35^\circ+\tan x}{1-\tan35^\circ\cdot\tan x}=\tan(35+x)=\frac4{CD}\\{}\\II&\text{On triangle}\;\;\Delta BCD:&\;\;\tan x=\frac1{CD}\end{cases}$$

Now develope I using II:

$$\frac4{CD}=\frac{\tan35^\circ+\frac1{CD}}{1-\tan35^\circ\cdot\frac1{CD}}$$

If you want now put $\;y:=CD\;,\;\;a:=\tan35^\circ\;$ to make things simpler, so that you have to solve the equation

$$\frac4y=\frac{a+\frac1y}{1-a\frac1y}=\frac{ay+1}{y-a}\iff4y-4a=ay^2+y\iff ay^2-3y+4a=0$$

Now solve the above quadratic and that's all...